# How to format to decimal number that include comma and dot in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I would like to know that how can i format my number including comma and dot to decimal. Thanks. In my database , my amount column is decimal type with (16,8) . after i formatting i want to save to database my number . For example
my input number 10,000.1111  and want to save as a 10000.1111 to my database. Thanks.

Comment: <?php
echo (float) str_replace(',', '', '10,000.1111')
?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this to format the string to a float, and remove the commas.

`(float) str_replace(',', '', '10,000.1111')`

Typecasting `(float)` will force the outputted variable as a float. And `str_replace()` will remove the commas from the inputted variable.

```
$input = '10,000.1111';
$model->column = (float) str_replace(',', '', $input);
$model->save()
```

Comment: Thanks sir. It Works.

Comment: No worries at all.